# [PHP]Arrays and Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays

Can you please tell what is wrong here, because i get an annoying message in my if statement:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

The code:

```
$maxlvls[14] = array(0, 30, 25, 20, 15, 1, 20, 25, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 20);

$lvle[14] = array(0, (int)$_GET['ratuszlvl'], (int)$_GET['koszarylvl'], (int)$_GET['stajnialvl'], (int)$_GET['warsztatlvl'], (int)$_GET['palaclvl'], (int)$_GET['kuznialvl'], (int)$_GET['ryneklvl'], (int)$_GET['tartaklvl'], (int)$_GET['cegielnialvl'], (int)$_GET['hutalvl'], (int)$_GET['zagrodalvl'], (int)$_GET['spichlerzlvl'], (int)$_GET['schoweklvl'], (int)$_GET['murlvl']);

if($lvle[1] <= $maxlvls[1] && $lvle[1] >= 0)
{
    echo "smth";
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect `$lvle[1]` to come from, if you only assigned a value to `$lvle[14]` …?

Comment: So it's not like in C++? :(

Comment: I'm really disapointed from the questions under this tag recently

Comment: @user3576397 does C++ allow you to set only 14th element in array, but to use its 1st element instead?

Comment: @user3576397 nope, arrays are dynamically sized.

Comment: @RoyalBg no, in C(++) you need to define the size of the array. That's the `[14]` (Not 14th element).

Comment: @bwoebi wow, I see. I have never been writing in C++, but have in Java and C# where the syntax for creating an array, differs from how you access it, so it's definetely not `arrayVar[14] = [1,2,4]; print arrayVar[2]`, is this in C++ (I will check right now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
$maxlvls[14] =
$lvle[14] =
```

Use just

```
$maxlvls = 
$lvle =
```

You don't have to declare (actually you *can't*) array's length in php(I guess you are doing this). However,assigning like :

```
$maxlvls[14] = array(...);
```

Means that you are assigning an array to the element of array `$maxlvls` with ***key*** `14`.

Comment: So simple explanation... It works and you are right that i was trying to set an array length. I'm new in PHP - previously i was learning C++.